# Split up Gruntfile

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My Gruntfile is becoming pretty big right now and I want to split it up into multiple files. I've Googled and experimented a lot but I can't get it to work.

I want something like this:

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: getConcatConfiguration()
  });
}
```

functions.js

```
function getConcatConfiguration() {
  // Do some stuff to generate and return configuration
}
```

How can I load functions.js into my Gruntfile.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How you can do it:**

you need to export your concat configuration, and require it in your Gruntfile (basic node.js stuff)!

i would recommend putting all every taskspecific configuration into one file named after the configuration (in this case i named it `concat.js`).

Moreover i moved `concat.js` into a folder named `grunt`

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: require('grunt/concat')(grunt);
  });
};
```

grunt/concat.js

```
module.exports = function getConcatConfiguration(grunt) {
  // Do some stuff to generate and return configuration
};
```

---

**How you SHOULD do it:**

there was already someone there who created a module named [load-grunt-config](https://www.npmjs.org/package/load-grunt-config). this does exactly what you want.

go ahead and put everything (as mentioned above) into separate files into a location of your choice (default folder ist `grunt`).

then your standard gruntfile should probably look like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);

  // define some alias tasks here
};
```

Comment: Your first part of the answer doesn't work. This is the code I used and the error I got: http://pastebin.com/tkTPWNjg I don't think the second part of your answer applies to my situation. I don't want to create Grunt tasks, I want to create JavaScript functions I can use. I read the documentation, but I cannot find how to dynamically generate the config (using a function) and assign its return value to the 'concat' property.

Comment: I found it already. You need to replace the first line of concat.js with "exports.getConcatConfiguration = function() {"

Comment: Now the next problem occurs: the grunt variable is not available in  concat.js.

Comment: i forgot to add braces on my require, see my edited answer now. you need to call the required function and pass grunt as parameter. *BUT* i highly recommend to use the [load-grunt-config](https://www.npmjs.org/package/load-grunt-config)-module!

Comment: For the first example it's working now, thanks! I want to use the load-grunt-config module, but I don't get how it works (like I said in an earlier comment).

Comment: just follow the instructions of the documentation. use the created grunt-folder, paste the code i put into example 2 in your gruntfile, and go from there: https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config#grunt-tasks-files

Comment: I installed it. Now, if for example in concat.js I say module.exports = { options: blablabla } then I want to dynamically generate that config at the top of the file. I need the grunt object for that. But it isn't available. It is available when I use module.exports = function(grunt) { } but then I don't know where to put the concat config.

Comment: Never mind, I understand how it works now. You can return a config object in the module.exports function. Thanks :)