# How to share configs with grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, nodes

I have 2 files that are the same, and only differs in 1 task. Is there anyway to re-use the configuration so it can be more maintainable? I'm looking for something like this:

> File1: config
>   File2: development tasks
>   File3: staging tasks
>   File4: production tasks
>   ....
>   Etc

Although the other question is similar in the end-result the configuration approach that I was looking for is much different. I have posted some comments with how the setup was done. Not optimal but it does the work and explains how to actually load the configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split up Gruntfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356538/split-up-gruntfile)

Answer (score 0):

After a lead from a friend I have found out that the way to do it is by using `grunt.config.merge`. With a bit more research on the subject I came across this setup that, is not optimal, but does the work and provides the solution that I was looking for:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e18fd95f3cc2ba8505a7

Comment: There is a grunt-config post on this blog that helps as well: http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/grunt-boilerplate.html